# Ejecutar un modal (JQuery) por PHP varias veces

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario que rellama a el mismo , todo ello en PHP . Si introduce una vez mal los datos , lanzo un modal por JQuery de la siguiente forma :

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>   $('#modal_errores').modal('show');</script>";
```

El problema viene cuando hay mas de una ejecuccion , ya que el modal , no se volveria mostrar . ¿ Alguna idea ?

A mi se me habria ocurrido hacerlo a traves de peticiones AJAX , pero eso haria cambiar completamente la dinamica ( y hacer un poco mas complejo el codigo por ende ).

```html
<?php 
  if(!isset($_POST["Correo-usuario"]){
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $('#modal_errores').modal('show');</script>";
  }
?>

<!--Formulario-->
<form action="./Login.php" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Correo-usuario">Usuario</label>
   <input type="email" name ="Correo-usuario" class="form-control" id="Correo-usuario" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Pass-usuario">Contraseña</label>
  <input type="text" name="Pass-usuario" class="form-control" id="Pass-usuario" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>
</form>

<!-- modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_errores" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

Comment: No se puede reproducir el problema ni siquiera una sola vez, podrías hacer que se replique el error?

Comment: @Roarca tu opcion es ajax y no seria tan complicado, un evento click con una ajax call apuntando a tu metodo login